# How to apply genetic algorithm to linear regression datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, genetic-algorithm

can we apply only genetic algorithm model on a dataset for linear regression? 
for example:
assume we have a dataset with features such as toffle score, cgpa, gre score ,etc and output values of chance of admission. In this we have to predict the chances of admission based on the features.[Link to the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mohansacharya/graduate-admissions)

Answer (score 0):

Lot of things are possible by using genetic algorithms. You just have to be sore that you are using correct dataset, you have to know what you want to get from it and last but not least, you have to know what exactly are you doing, which means you need to have correct fitness function :)